# Problem with qraphQL after upgrading from quarkus 2.8.3.Final to quarkus 3.6.7

Tags: json, graphql, quarkus

It all worked perfect before the upgrade but after the upgrade I receive this error:

"Exception occurred in target VM: class jakarta.json.JsonValueImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.json.JsonObject"
java.lang.ClassCastException:
class jakarta.json.JsonValueImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.json.JsonObject
(jakarta.json.JsonValueImpl and jakarta.json.JsonObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.eclipse.parsson.JsonObjectBuilderImpl$JsonObjectImpl.getJsonObject(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:234)
at io.smallrye.graphql.client.impl.ResponseReader.readFrom(ResponseReader.java:99)
at io.smallrye.graphql.client.vertx.dynamic.VertxDynamicGraphQLClient.lambda$executeSingleResultOperationOverHttp$10(VertxDynamicGraphQLClient.java:451)
at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:36)
at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualBiConsumer.accept(SlowContextualBiConsumer.java:21)

I get the error when I execute this code:

```
var response = client.executeSync(query, variables);
```

where query is a String, and variables is of type Map<String,Object>

The response looks like this:

```
{
"data": {
"Subscriptions": {
"select": []
}
}, 
"errors": [],
"extensions": null
}
```

The ClassCastException is thrown because of the field:
"extensions": null

With
"extensions": {}
it works fine.

Maybe null is a non-valid value per the GraphQL specification?

It seems that json handling differs between quarkus versions. Version 2 includes javax.json and version 3 includes jakarta.json

I expected it to work exactly the same after the upgrade to quarkus 3.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you've found a bug. I've reported it as https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql/issues/2057 and we will take care of it. Feel free to watch the issue for updates.